# Dictionary and BackGroundWorker, getting an InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#

I must have misunderstood something, as I don't know why this wont work.

I have a Dictionary called loadfile.

```
public Dictionary<string, string> loadfile;
```

This Dictionary is populated with entries that is read from a file.

As an example, if I do the following?

```
MessageBox.Show(loadfile["someentry"]);
```

The messagebox appears with the value from the string, 'someentry'.

However.. If I do the same thing, but instead of showing it in a messagebox, I want to show it in a textbox like so:

```
textBox1.Text = loadfile["someentry"];
```

It throws an exception (I'm running it inside a try-catch).

What have I missed here?

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: I assume that the dictionary doesn't contain a key `someentry` where you want to assign it's value to the `TextBox.Text`. Can you show more code?

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException - Can it be because im running it inside a background worker?

Comment: Yes.. if you're trying to access UI elements from a non-UI thread.. you're going to run into trouble.

Comment: Tim Schmelter it does contain it, right before i want to load it to the textbox, i use the messagebox to show it, and that gives me the expected output

Comment: @DanielJørgensen Yes. Show the code on how you use your background worker. What's the complete exception bro. `InvalidOperationException` what? Can't manipulate update something because it's in a different thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> System.InvalidOperationException - Can it be because im running it inside a background worker?

Yes, this is likely the problem. The problem isn't getting the value from the dictionary, but rather setting the `.Text` property of the user interface element.

All UI access must be done on the UI thread.  You'll need to marshal the call back to the UI 
thread via `Control.Invoke` (Windows Forms) or `Dispatcher.Invoke` (WPF).

For example, if this is Windows Forms, you can do:

```
var entry = loadfile["someentry"];
textBox1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => textBox1.Text = entry));
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
textBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox1.Text = loadfile["someentry"]));
```

If you are using `BackgroundWorker`, you probably just want to subscribe to the `CompletedEventArgs` and `DoWork`.

Where in `DoWork` you set the result of the `Backgroundworker`

and in `CompletedEventArgs` you update the `TextBox`. The CompletedEventArgs will run in the `Dispatcher` thread

Sample usage of BackgroundWorker

```
private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = e.Result.ToString();
}

private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   //Load your dictionary or something and set the result here like 
   //e.Result = SomeAction 

}
```